# A doubt in the proof of $\mathbb{Z} + \mathbb{Z}\sqrt m$ is not Euclidean with respect to $\phi_m$

Tags: quadratic-residues, integral-domain, euclidean-domain

I am reading 'Introductory Algebraic Number Theory' written by Saban Alaca and Kenneth S. Williams.

Theorem 2.3.1 says that

> Let m be a positive squarefree integer. If there exist distinct odd
> primes p and q such that
> $$\left( \frac mp \right) = \left( \frac mq \right) = -1$$
> and positive integers $t$ and $u$ such that
> $pt + qu = m$, $p \nmid t$, $q \nmid u$
> and an integer $r$ such that
> $r ^2 ≡ pt \mod m$,
> then $\mathbb{Z} + \mathbb{Z}\sqrt m$ is not Euclidean with respect to $\phi_m$

where $\phi_m(a + b \sqrt m) = \vert a^2 - mb^2 \vert $ and $()$ is Legendre symbol for quadratic residues.

In the proof, the author assumes that $\mathbb{Z} + \mathbb{Z}\sqrt m$ is Euclidean and then applies Euclidean algorithm to $r\sqrt m$ and $m$ and arrives statement that there are $x$ and $y$ in integers (more specifically $x + y \sqrt m$ is a qoutient obtained when we apply Euclidean algorithm to $r\sqrt m$ and $m$) such that $mx^2 - (my - r)^2 = -pt \text{ or } qu$. Take $X = x$ and $Y = my - r$ so that we will have
$$ mX^2 - Y^2 = -pt \text{ or } qu$$
Suppose $$ mX^2 - Y^2 = -pt $$
By hypothesis we must have $p \nmid m$  since $\left( \frac mp \right )  =  -1 $.
Now the author claims that

> Also, as $p \nmid t$ we have $p \, \, \vert \vert −pt$. Hence $p \nmid X$ and $p \nmid Y$.

and arrives at contradiction. I do not see the logic used to conclude $p \nmid X$ and $p \nmid Y$. In the other case also the author makes similar claim. Since $p$ divides $pt$ and $p \nmid m$, $p$ should divide both of $X$ and $Y$ or none of them. So it is enough to show that one of them is not divisible by $p$. I do not see any reason to think $p \nmid x$ or $p \nmid my - r$. Where I am missing the logic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a binary quadratic form
$$ f(x,y) = a x^2 + b xy+ c y^2   $$
with $a,b,c$ integers.
Given
$$  \Delta = b^2 - 4 a c,  $$
where we require that $\Delta,$ if non-negative, is not a square (so also $\Delta \neq 0,1$).

**Proposition:** given an odd prime $q$ such that $q$ does not divide $\Delta$ and, in fact, $$ (\Delta| q) = -1, $$
whenever $$ f(x,y) \equiv 0 \pmod q,   $$ then BOTH
$$ x \equiv 0 \pmod q, \; \; \; \; \; y \equiv 0 \pmod q.   $$

**Proof:** the integers taken $\pmod q$ form a field; every nonzero element has a multiplicative inverse. If either $a,c$ were divisible by $q,$ we would have $\Delta $ equivalent to $b^2$ mod $q,$ which would cause $(\Delta|q)$ to be $1$ rather than $-1.$ As a result, neither $a$ nor $c$ is divisible by $q.$

Next, $q$ is odd, so that $2$ and $4$ have multiplicative inverses mod $q,$ they are non zero in the field. Put togethaer, $$4a \neq 0 \pmod q$$

Now, complete the square:
$$ a x^2 + b xy+ c y^2 \equiv 0 \pmod q  $$
if and only if
$$ 4a(a x^2 + b xy+ c y^2) \equiv 0 \pmod q,  $$
$$ 4a^2 x^2 + 4abxy + 4ac y^2   \equiv 0 \pmod q,       $$
$$ 4a^2 x^2 + 4abxy + (b^2 y^2 - b^2 y^2) + 4ac y^2   \equiv 0 \pmod q,       $$
$$ 4a^2 x^2 + 4abxy + b^2 y^2 - (b^2 y^2 - 4ac y^2)   \equiv 0 \pmod q,       $$
$$ (4a^2 x^2 + 4abxy + b^2 y^2) - (b^2  - 4ac) y^2   \equiv 0 \pmod q,       $$
$$ (2ax + by)^2 - (b^2  - 4ac) y^2   \equiv 0 \pmod q,       $$
$$ (2ax + by)^2 - \Delta y^2   \equiv 0 \pmod q,       $$
$$ (2ax + by)^2 \equiv \Delta y^2   \pmod q.       $$

Now, ASSUME that $y \neq 0 \pmod q.$ Then $y$ has a multiplicative inverse which we are allowed to call $1/y,$ and we have
$$ \frac{(2ax + by)^2}{y^2} \equiv \Delta   \pmod q,       $$
$$ \left( \frac{2ax + by}{y} \right)^2 \equiv \Delta   \pmod q.       $$
However, the HYPOTHESIS that $ (\Delta| q) = -1 $ says that this is impossible, thus contradicting the assumption that $y \neq 0 \pmod q.$

So, in fact, $y \equiv 0 \pmod q.$ The original equation now reads
$$ a x^2  \equiv 0 \pmod q  $$ with the knowledge that $a \neq 0 \pmod q,$ so we also get
$$ x \equiv 0 \pmod q, \; \; \; \; \; y \equiv 0 \pmod q.   $$
$$ \bigcirc   \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$

Comment: Thank you. That is an excellent answer.

Answer (score 0):

They may have this  **Lemma**  earlier : Given a quadratic form with integer coefficients
$$   f(x,y) = a x^2 + b xy + c y^2 $$
and discriminant
$$  \Delta = b^2 - 4ac $$
which is not permitted to be any integer square.

If we have a prime $s$   with Legendre symbol
$$   \left( \Delta | s \right)  = -1 $$  along with particular integers $x,y$ such that
$$ ax^2 + bxy + c y^2 \equiv 0 \pmod s,  $$
it follows that both $ x \equiv 0 \pmod s$  and $ y \equiv 0 \pmod s \; ; \; \;$   finally we see $ ax^2 + bxy + c y^2 \equiv 0 \pmod {s^2}.  $

The application in your book is that the discriminant of $m X^2 - Y^2 $  is $\Delta =4m.$ This is a nonresidue for primes $p,q.$ They do point out that $p^2$ does not divide $m X^2 - Y^2 ,$   but $p$ does. If $p$ divided one of $X,Y$ it would necessarily divide the other one, but that would make $p^2$  divide  $m X^2 - Y^2 $ and a contradiction.

Hmmm.. Now that I write it down, maybe my Lemma is not needed explicitly in this case.

Comment: I did not find the Lemma in the book till now. Could you please show how it is proved or some references to it?